# How do I get rid of the red highlighting when writing a makefile in Vim

Tags: vim, makefile

I am writing a makefile and it keeps highlighting every word after the tab. This is an example:

[image]

This my .vimrc file:

```
filetype indent off  
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
syntax on  
colorscheme slate
set ignorecase
set number 
set nosmartindent
set noswapfile
set list
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:`,extends:>,precedes:<
set lcs+=space:·
```

How can I only get rid of the red highlighting? I know `:syntax off` will get rid of it, but it gets rid of all sorts of color changes which are useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you say there is a tab, there is no tab, but four spaces (as indicated by the four dots which you have configured by setting `lcs`).

That's an error and it's why it is highlighted in red.

To fix it, insert an actual tab character instead.